# переменная экземпляра == объект?

Tags: java

```
Test test1 = new Test();
```

test1 - это переменная экземпляра?
Не могу понять что такое переменная экземпляра :(

Comment: Если она объявлена в классе вне метода, то да. Иначе - это локальная переменная метода

Comment: *"Мать любит дочь."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test1 - это экземпляр класса(объект),  экземпляр класса = объект, объект класса.

Пример создания экземпляра класса:

```
Test test1 = new Test(); // Т.е. , то, что вы и предложили
```

Переменные:

- Локальные

  - Локальные переменные объявляются в методах, конструкторах или блоках. Блок - {  ...  }
  - Локальные переменные создаются, когда метод, конструктор или блок запускается и уничтожаются после того, как завершиться метод, конструктор или блок.
  - Модификаторы доступа нельзя использовать для локальных переменных.
  - Они являются видимыми только в пределах объявленного метода, конструктора или блока.

Пример:

```html
public void age() {
      //Локальная переменная в методе 
      int age = 0;
      System.out.println("Возраст -  " + age);
   }
```

- Класса(или статические)

  - Переменные класса известны как статические переменные и объявляются при помощи ключевого слова “static ”, внутри класса, но не в методах и конструкторах.
  - Значение переменной может быть только одно, не смотря на то сколько было создано объектов.
  - Статические переменные часто используются в качестве констант. Константная переменная объявляется как final и static с модификатором доступа или public или private.
  - Константным переменным значение присваивается при объявлении и не изменятся на протяжение выполнения программы.
  - Статические переменные создаются в момент запуска программы и уничтожаются только при завершение работы программы.
  - Область видимости аналогична переменным экземпляра.
  - Переменные экземпляра имеют значение по умолчанию:

    - Для числовых типов = 0
    - Для Boolean = false
    - Для объектов = null
  - Для вызова статической переменной за пределами класса, необходимо использовать полное имя класса и имя переменной. Например: ObjectReference.VariableName.

Пример:

```html
public class test{
   // Переменные класса
   private static double salary;
   
   public static int age;
}
```

- Экземпляра

  - Переменные экземпляра – объявляются в классе и доступны любому методу класса, так и снаружи класса.
  - Переменные экземпляра создаются в момент создания объекта при помощи ключевого слово “new”, а уничтожаются вместе с методом.
  - Переменные экземпляра обычно содержат значения на которые ссылаются более одного метода класса.
  - Переменным экземпляра могут быть назначены модификаторы доступа.
  - Переменные экземпляра предназначенные для использования внутри класса – обычно получают модификатор доступа private. В случаи необходимости передачи значения в подклассы, можно присвоить модификатор доступа protected.
  - Переменные экземпляра имеют значение по умолчанию:

    - Для числовых типов = 0
    - Для Boolean = false
    - Для объектов = null

Пример:

```html
public class test{

    // Переменная экземпляра.
   public String name;
   
   // Переменная экземпляра.
   private int age;

  //... (Остальное упущено, конструкторы и т.д.)
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ, вы меня спасаете)

Comment: @MikeMclaren , удачи в разработке )

Answer (score 4):

```
class SomeClass {
    Test test1 = new Test(); // переменная экземпляра (instance variable)
    static Test test2 = new Test(); // переменная класса

    void someMethod() {
        Test test1 = new Test(); // локальная переменная
    }
}
```

Comment: очень понравился Ваш коментарий. Помогите пожалуйста понять. Вы написали: 

static Test test2 = new Test(); // переменная класса. 
У Шилдта написанно:
 "Переменные экземпляра, объявленные как static, по существу, являются глобальными." 
ВОПРОС: "глобальная переменная" и "переменная класса" это одно и то же?

Comment: @Marika по сути да

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ

Answer (score 0):

`new Test()` - создаем объект (экземпляр класса `Test`)

`Test test1` - переменная с типом `Test`, которая

- может содержать сылку на конкретный объект (экземпляр)
- значение `null`
- либо быть не проинициализированной переменной (см. случай локальных переменных)

`Test test1 = new Test();` - переменной `test1` присвоили ссылку на объект

Переменная - не равно объект, это ссылка на объект.

```
Test test1 = new Test();
Test test2 = test1;
```

Здесь две переменные test1, test2 содержат ссылку на один и тот же объект.

Что такое `переменная экземпляра` - мне тоже не понятно. Нужно смотреть в контексте остального текста, где эта фраза встречается. Возможно это поле объекта, как предполагают в др ответах, а может быть просто кривой перевод.

Answer (score 0):

ДА. 
"Шаблоном" или "описанием объекта" является класс, а "объект" представляет "экземпляр" этого класса. 
[Источник](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.1.php)