# Что такое "экземпляр класса" в Java?

Tags: java, терминология

Правильно ли я понимаю, что экземпляр класа в Java - это обьект класса?
Например:

```
public class Cat{

 public void meow() {
 System.out.println("Meow");
 }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

Cat cat = new Cat();

}
```

И именно cat - это обьект класса, или экземпляр, или одно и тоже?
Если нет, то не могли бы вы обьяснить на примере простого кода с комментариями?

Comment: Допустил ошибку с своём ответе, обновил

Comment: Объект класса - это класс, экземпляр класса - это объект, у него есть ссылка, вы ее присваивает переменной. Попробуйте нарисовать логическую схему.

Comment: Получается, обьект класса - это ссылка на класс?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какая разница между экземпляром и объектом класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519461/); [переменная экземпляра == объект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968421/).

Comment: у java достаточно объёмная экосистема для изучения, и подобное словоблудие засоряет мозги ненужной информацией, поверьте

Comment: Класс -- это чертеж, а экземпляр класса (объект) -- это изделие, созданное по чертежу

Comment: Либо, другими словами, представьте себе, что определённая модель автомобиля - это класс, а конкретный автомобиль с номером/хозяином - это экземпляр класса модели автомобиля.

Comment: @avp
Я знаю что такое класс и обьект, я просто не понимаю, почему иногда обьект называют именно экземпляром, и хотел понять, есть ли разница в целом, ведь в моем понимании: обьект имеет описание, а экземпляр - нет. Но если разницы нет - тогда все более менее понятно. Все равно я только учусь, так что пока мне знание разницы не существенно. Подросту и почитаю документацию, спасибо

Comment: @OleksiiShpak, не уверен, что называющий в данный момент эту штуку объектом или экземпляром вообще задумывается, а каким из слов вот сейчас ее лучше обозвать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс это определённая структура, которая определяет как хранятся данные в определённом участке памяти - объекте. Создавая экземпляр класса (Да, объект это экземпляр класса) вы выделяете новый участок памяти с теми полями и методами, что прописаны внутри класса

Например:

```java
public class Cat {
    public int age = 0;
    public String WhatYoureAge() {
        return "Meow (My age is " + age + ")";
    }
}
```

```java
Cat cat1 = new Cat();
Cat cat2 = new Cat();

cat1.age = 4;
cat2.age = 6;

System.out.println(cat1.WhatYoureAge()) // Meow (My age is 4)
System.out.println(cat2.WhatYoureAge()) // Meow (My age is 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Экземпляр класса или instance по сути это описание определенного объекта в памяти.